# Preserving old Typewritten pages from 1925?

Tags: preservation

After my grandmother passed away my mother received all of her old photos and documents. I have been going through these and have found an old genealogy manuscript written by a distant relative in 1925.

The book is "bound" between two sheets of vinyl with what appears to be a shoelace. It is not easy to flip through and read, and some of the pages are beginning to show signs of wear.

My question is: what should I do to preserve these pages in a way that not only keeps them safe, but also easy to flip through. I was thinking some sort of plastic sleeves in a bound-together book, but wanted to know what this community thought and if they have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to both preserve old documents or photos and also handle them a lot.

My suggestion would be to:

1. Scan all the pages (or photograph if it is not possible to place
   flat on a scanner)
2. Store the originals in a cool, dry, and secure
   place
3. Print out copies of the scans if you want to flip through or
   share them

A minimal ammount of handling will keep the originals in their best state. If you use the scans or copies to work with on a regular basis, then you do not risk damaging them. You could print out the copies and bind them together into a book form if that is preferable.

Comment: I planned on making digital copies regardless. If they were to be placed in sleeves and those sleeves then placed in a binder, they would not be handled much. I just wanted a way that they could be handled _if_ necessary. Do you think they would still be subject to damage in that scenario? I'm new to genealogy and preserving documents so thank you for your help!